# Create unique index in ArangoDB edge collection for multiple path attributes including _from and _to attributes

Tags: arangodb

I am trying to set a unique constraint for an edge collection so that only one edge of a certain type can be created between two given nodes. The issue is that it seems I can't use `_from` and `_to` attributes as path attributes when creating the index. What I have tried so far:

```
db._collection('edges').ensureUniqueConstraint('_from', '_to', 'type');
```

I get the following error:

```
[ArangoError 10: bad parameter]
```

I don't want to check whether a certain edge type between two nodes exists before creating it.

Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is currently not possible to create secondary indexes on internal attributes such as _key, _id, _rev, _from, or _to. We want to allow this for a future version of ArangoDB, but it will be a massive code change.

The only way to achieve the desired result is to create an extra attribute in the edge that you save and put the combination of "_from", "_to", and "type" into it. I think these values should be known at edge creation already.

So instead of saving an edge like this

```
db.edges.save(_from, _to, { type: type, other: ... });
```

it should be like this:

```
// create a unique index on attribute "unique"
db._collection("edges").ensureUniqueConstraint("unique");

// create a variable "unique" which contains the values of _from and _to and type
var unique = _from + "-" + _to + "-" + String(type);

// now save the edge, using the "unique" attribute
db.edges.save(_from, _to, { type: type, unique: unique, other: ... });
```

This is a workaround, but it should solve that particular problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out (wanted to be sure this feature was not available yet). It should do the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Since ArangoDB 3.0 you can [ensure uniqueness of relations in edge collections](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/Manual/Indexing/Hash.html#ensure-uniqueness-of-relations-in-edge-collections) with unique hash index on `_from` and `_to` fields.

`db.edgeCollectionName.ensureIndex({ type: "hash", fields: [ "_from", "_to" ], unique: true });`

When a **A->B** relation exists, another **A->B** won't be created. **B->A** can still be created, though.

Comment: And you could always sort A and B before creating the hash to make it work for both A->B and B->A.